# Using subclasses as item controllers in ember

Tags: ember.js

I have an ArrayController managing a collection of items of different flavors. To handle them, I have several item controllers, all subclassed from a generic item controller:

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    lookupItemController: function (object) {
        switch (object.get('type')) {
            case 'type1': return 'ItemType1';
            case 'type2': return 'ItemType2';
        }
    }
});

//superclass for item controller
App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    ...common logic to all item controllers
});

App.ItemType1Controller = App.ItemController.extend({
    msg: 'I am of type1',
    init: function() {console.log('in App.ItemType1Controller');}
});

App.ItemType2Controller = App.ItemController.extend({
    msg: 'I am of type2'
});
```

My first question is the correct syntax/format of the return value from `lookupItemController`. I tried `'App.ItemType1Controller'` but that yields controller not found. The examples in the documentation show that returning `'field'` means `App.FieldController`, but what should it be in my case?

Returning `'ItemType1'` avoids any error, but the `init` hook is never invoked, and the `msg` property is undefined when used in a template such as

```
{{#each controller}}
    {{msg}}
{{/each}}
```

I tried stepping through the ember code but got lost in a maze of containers, parsers, and factories. Is there something wrong with what I'm trying to do, and what is the right way to accomplish it?

**UPDATE**

The answers helped me to solve my problem, which actually lay elsewhere. I had been subsetting the model as in

```
filteredContent: Ember.computed.filter('content', ...)
```

and then each'ing over it in the template

```
{{each filteredContent}}
```

and the problem was that the result of `lookupItemController` was not getting associated with each record within the collection (`#each controller` works fine). I still do not know how to solve this, so I took a different route, but it would be nice to know how to make `{{each}}` loop while assigning the custom controller to each item.

Answer (score 2):

The default `lookupItemController` in the ember source is the following:

```
lookupItemController: function(object) {
  return get(this, 'itemController');
}
```

So you can use any valid format, in the same way when itemController property is hardcoded in the controller, like:

```
App.MyArrayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'myFoo'
});
```

This is documented [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#method_lookupItemController)

In the end the itemController property will be used in the container, to retrieve a item controller instance, in that way:

```
container.lookup('controller:' + itemController);
```

Given a `App.MyFooController` you can use `my.foo`, `myFoo`, `MyFoo` and `my_foo`.

In your case you can do the following:

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    lookupItemController: function (object) {
        switch (object.get('type')) {
            case 'type1': return 'itemType1';
            case 'type2': return 'itemType2';
        }
    }
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Great answer. This is also documented in the API docs: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#method_lookupItemController

Comment: but the cameliness doesn't matter, his original form should work too. I just double-checked in my app:  `itemType1`, `ItemType1` and `item_type_1` should all work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments Luke and Michael. I updated the answer to give more informations.